# How do I map an Azure File Share as a volume in a Docker Compose file?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-storage, azure-files

I have so far only found examples on how to create a volume on the host machine, e.g:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
       - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

So this defines a volume named db-data that will physically be stored on the host machine running the container.

Is is possible to makes the db-data volume point to an Azure File Share in an Azure Storage account and how would I specify the needed parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The format that works for me currently is:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myfileshare
      storage_account_name: mystorageaccount
```

Comment: what about the account key etc? There isn't enough info specified here to connect securely so how does that work - any tips?

Comment: This answer is for container instance service, not app service I think.

Answer (score 0):

From CLI you can create with:

```
docker volume create -d azurefile -o share=myvol --name vol1 

docker run -i -t -v vol1:/data busybox
```

In your compose you need to use this skeleton:

```
volumes:
  myvol:
    driver: azurefile
    driver_opts:
      accountname: ___your__account_name
      accountkey: ___your_account_key
      share: "volumes"
      remotepath: "myvol"
```

UPDATE:

These options are now deprecated, please follow instruction for CloudStor plugin at:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it on the command line, but how do I create a volume in a docker compose file?

Comment: I added info to my answer

Comment: In my scenario (Azure Web App for Containers) I cannot run anything, I can only upload a docker compose file. So can I create a volume using a docker compose file?

Comment: Hi Nicola, I tried the compose file skeleton you have here but it complained that accountname and accountkey are not recognised volume drive options. Any idea why?

Comment: The CloudStor documentation linked doesn't talk about a compose file.....

Comment: Docker Docs link is now dead, having trouble locating a replacement.

Comment: @MathiasRönnlund here is the Azure guide for storage with app service containers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage

Comment: How do I do that while this option is now deprecated?